# Call public void from a code file in main form

Tags: c#, forms, void, public

I want to call a void like this:

```
public void test()
{
// Blah blah.
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
test();
}
```

But in this case, I want to call a public void from another .cs file in another .cs file.

Comment: Right, so you'll need to call it on a specific instance of the other class. I'm afraid Stack Overflow isn't a great site to learn the core aspects of a language from - I'd strongly recommend that you get hold of a good tutorial or book.

Comment: As long as `test()` is declared public and static you can call it from anywhere with `the.name.space.its.in.TheClassItsIn.test()`. Otherwise if it's not static you'll need to create a `new TheClassItsIn()` and call `.test()` on it. Some more context might help explain what you're really trying to do. The question as asked doesn't really have a good application.

Answer (score 0):

First off you declare your class and create an instance of it.

```
  YourClassName myNewClass = new YourClassName();
```

and then on your button1_Click you call the function from your instance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myNewClass.test();
}
```

Or you could make your classe Static, in that case you go to your class and where it says

```
 Class YourClassName;
```

you change to:

```
 Static Class YourClassName;
```

and on the button_Click Method, this time you call the class itself, and not the instance because Static Classes can only have one instance:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   YourClassName.test();
}
```